# How do I dynamically build a Mongodb aggregation statement?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

In the following function I am trying to dynamically build a mongo `$or` query condition. The priceRanges is received as a parameter to the function. I iterate over `priceRanges` as follows to build the `$or` statement for my projection:

```
    let $or = [];

    for(let filter of priceRanges) {
        $or.push( { $gte: [ "$price", +filter.low ] }, { $lte: [ "$price", +filter.high ] })
    }
```

The `$or` array now contains the following values:

```
console.log('$or', $or)

    $or [ 
          { '$gte': [ '$price', 100 ] }, { '$lte': [ '$price', 200 ] },
          { '$gte': [ '$price', 200 ] }, { '$lte': [ '$price', 300 ] },
          { '$gte': [ '$price', 300 ] }, { '$lte': [ '$price', 400 ] } 
        ]
```

Here I build the project statement:

```
let $project = {
        name:1,
        producttype:1,
        brand:1,
        model:1,
        price:1,
        list_price:1,
        description:1,
        rating:1,
        sku:1,
        feature:1,
        image:1,
        images: 1,
        specifications:1,        
     };
```

I append the `$or` condition to the projection:

```
$project.priceRange = {$or: $or};
```

The $or statement looks like this:

```
{ '$or':
   [ { '$gte': [Array] },{ '$lte': [Array] },
 { '$gte': [Array] }, { '$lte': [Array] },
 { '$gte': [Array] }, { '$lte': [Array] } ] }
```

I create an array of my projection statement:

```
aggregateArray.push({$project: $project});
```

`console.log(aggregateArray)` looks like this:

```
aggregateArray [ { '$project':
 { name: 1,
   producttype: 1,
   brand: 1,
   model: 1,
   price: 1,
   list_price: 1,
   description: 1,
   rating: 1,
   sku: 1,
   feature: 1,
   image: 1,
   images: 1,
   specifications: 1,
   priceRange: [Object] } },
  { '$skip': 1 },
  { '$limit': 4 } ]
```

I execute the projection as follows:

```
let products = await Product.aggregate(aggregateArray);
```

When executed, the `$or` statement doesn't seem to have any effect. The result contains random prices and not the ranges specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that javascript array's `push` methods takes an array of values as a parameter so `$or.push( { $gte: [ "$price", +filter.low ] }, { $lte: [ "$price", +filter.high ] })` pushes two separate filtering conditions. Therefore `price` equal to `50` will also be included in your result since it matches second condition (lower than `200`). To fix that you need to combine those pairs using [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) so your final filtering condition should look like this:

```
var $or =  [ 
            { $and: [ { '$gte': [ '$price', 100 ] }, { '$lte': [ '$price', 200 ] } ] },
            { $and: [ { '$gte': [ '$price', 200 ] }, { '$lte': [ '$price', 300 ] } ] },
            { $and: [ { '$gte': [ '$price', 300 ] }, { '$lte': [ '$price', 400 ] } ] }
        ]
```

Then if you need it for filtering it should be using with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) inside of [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) stage.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { $expr: { $or: $or } }
    },
    // other aggregation stages
])
```